# Why do headhunters try to get the resume or cv by all means?

Tags: recruitment

Sometimes, headhunters make me scratch my head with their behaviors. Here, I write one instance I had with a headhunter.

I hope someone can explain what's going on with them.

One headhunter contacted me around 2 months asking my cv. I was not looking for a new job and was very busy with my work so I couldn't find time to update my cv. Also, I didn't want to send my cv when I didn't look for a job and I was not pleased with his contact. But he repeatedly messaged me through Linkedin and eventually, I wrote one for him. And as soon as I sent him my cv, I couldn't reach him anymore. I asked him what's going on but no answer. He didn't introduce any opportunity either.

I guessed that he might need only my cv and nothing else. Why does headhunter need cv? Can they make money only with applicants' cv?

Comment: Give him some feedback on LinkedIn as well as on here - name would be a good start. The power of social apps to get recruiters to behave better.

Comment: It does not look like an actual SE question to me cause we should give our speculations here.

Comment: @Iman I think if someone has experiences with headhunter thing, they can make a reasonable conclusion. And I don't know if any answer is possible without a bit of speculation on the workplace questions. I feel a lot of the answers here are a combination of limited experiences and speculation rather than scientific research.

Comment: Most headhunters are annoying as hell. Occasionally I do come across good ones. And the few times that happens, I always make sure to commend them.

Comment: Are you sure it was a real headhunter and not a scammer trying to get your contact information?

Comment: @kevin012 Yes Kevin, you are right. Convinced!

Comment: @SolarMike This happened several years ago and I forgot his name now. I just curious from time to time why he behaved in the way.

Comment: Ask a very simple question to detect wether you're talking to a bot or not. If you are, send the CV of Jonh Doe, drug dealer, behind bars. And some unhappy comment on their linkedin profile. The worst thing that may happen to you when automating a task is having someone feed you troll data. They don't care about your time, make them pay with time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many recruiters are playing a numbers game. They are going for quantity over quality. Collect as many resumes as possible, send them to as many companies as possible, and collect the commission when one bites. They are not trying to achieve a high success *rate*, they are trying to achieve a high success *frequency* through sheer volume.

Recruiters who operate that way often use a lot of automation to safe time. They automatically skim platforms like Linkedin or Stackoverflow Jobs, automatically write emails to people who match certain criteria and automatically write followups if they didn't respond within X days. They don't manually interact with individual applicants after they got their resume, because that's not an efficient use of their time.

**Should you use such a recruiter?** Well, if your job search strategy would be basically the same - send the same application to any company you can find and sort through those which reply - then why not. You can just as well outsource that process. But if you prefer to thoroughly look for companies and apply to those you really want to work at by hand-tailoring your application for every company (yes, they can tell the difference), then such a recruiter is not a good fit for you.

Answer (score 6):

In my experiences 99.9% of "recruiters" that reach out to you for CV with no position in mind a low level / starting employees that have to show work for their bosses, result is NOT their goal, all they want is your name with file in their weekly / monthly report

Do not get hammered in to doing anything you do not want / need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly had a good lead for which you were a match which then dried up, or went to another candidate or agency.

Alternative Scenarios:
Multiply this (CV gathering) by 1000 (or some large number) and the headhunter company can boast about having 1000 qualified candidates available to their clients. The fact you are not actively looking is a minor consideration.

Worst case (and I have seen and experienced this) is they take a good CV and change the contact and name details to that of a candidate they need to place.